# Docker volume not working with Docker-compose to generate Doxygen documentation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm trying to generate a `Doxygen` documentation in a `Dockerfile` using a `Docker-compose` to run all the services at the same time.

The goal is to generate the documentation in the container and to retrieve the generated files in local.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y doxygen doxygen-gui doxygen-doc graphviz

WORKDIR /doc

COPY Doxyfile .
COPY logo.png .

RUN doxygen Doxyfile
```

Here is the `docker-compose` with the doc service:

```
version: "3"

services:
  doc:
    build: ./doc
    volumes:
      - ./documentation:/doc
```

The doc is generated on the container and a new directory named "documentation" is generated but it is empty. How can I solve it to be filled with the generated documentation from the container ?

Comment: If you change that `RUN` with a `CMD`, and you re-build, does it behave like you expect?

Comment: The problem is not the command, the doc is well generated in `Docker`. The problem is the volume, the `doc` folder in the container does not appear in local.

Comment: `RUN` run on build, `CMD` run when you start the container. In the first case your volume is not mounted yet, because is building the image. With `CMD`, it run after the volume is mounted. Can you humour me and try it before we look at other causes, so we can exclude it?

Comment: I already tried your solution but it doesn't works for me. Here is the error output: `error: configuration file Doxyfile not found!`

Comment: Try moving the Doxyfile file into the `./documentation` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is to generate the documentation in the container and to
>   retrieve the generated files in local.

You use a local directory as source of the mount here : `- ./documentation:/doc`.
It will make the `/doc` directory on the container to be synchronized with the `./documentation` on the host but the source of the content is the host, not the container.
To get generated files on the host you can use a named volume instead of  :

```
volumes:
   - documentation-doxygen:/doc
```

After the container run you could get more information on that volume (location among other things) with `docker volume inspect documentation-doxygen`.

But if you mount the volume only to get the created folder, I think that you don't need to use volume at all.
A straighter alternative is simply doing the copy of the folder on the host after the container run :

```
docker copy DOC_CONTAINER_ID:/doc ./documentation-doxygen
```

As another alternative, if you want to execute `doxygen Doxyfile` in a local context in terms of folder but in a container (possible way in local env), you could replace `RUN` BY `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to execute it as the container startup command and mount the current directory as a bind mount.
It will spare you some copies in the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y doxygen doxygen-gui doxygen-doc graphviz

WORKDIR /doc

# REMOVE THAT COPY Doxyfile .
# REMOVE THAT COPY logo.png .

ENTRYPOINT doxygen Doxyfile
```

And the docker-compose part :

```
version: "3"

services:
  doc:
    build: ./doc
    volumes:
      - ./:/doc
```

Here `./`is specified to use as bind source the base directory of the context of the `doc` service.